# Python OpenCV Duplicate a transparent shape in the same image

Tags: numpy, opencv, transparent, alpha

I have an image of a circle, refer to the image attached below. I already retrieved the transparent circle and want to paste that circle back to the image to make some overlapped circles.

Below is my code but it led to the problem A, it's like a (transparent) hole in the image. I need to have circles on normal white background.

```
height, width, channels = circle.shape
original_image[60:60+height, 40:40+width] = circle
```

I used cv2.addWeighted but got blending issue, I need clear circles

```
circle = cv2.addWeighted(original_image[60:60+height, 40:40+width],0.5,circle,0.5,0)
original_image[60:60+rows, 40:40+cols] = circle
```

[image: Need to implement the flow to B]

Comment: there you go https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780

Comment: if your source data has no transparency information, you'll have to create it. given that your foreground object is a black circle on white background, you could use that intensity as an alpha channel. but then you'd have to remove the "white" components from the edge pixels. it's complicated.

Comment: or you could implement one of the blending modes that are known from image editors. "darken" or something like that? the equations float around on the internet.

Comment: In case you have a black circle on white background, you can create two images (little larger), one with a circle on the left side, and one image with a circle on the right side... Instead of using `cv2.addWeighted`, you may get the minimum (use `cv2.min`). In case the images has an alpha channel you have to get the maximum of the two alpha channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a transparent black circle, then in Python/OpenCV here is one way to do that.

```
 - Read the transparent image unchanged
 - Extract the bgr channels and the alpha channel
 - Create a colored image of the background color and size desired
 - Create similar sized white and black images
 - Initialize a copy of the background color image for the output
 - Define a list offset coordinates in the larger image
 - Loop for over the list of offsets and do the following
 - Insert the bgr image into a copy of the white image as the base image
 - Insert the alpha channel into a copy of the black image for a mask
 - composite the initialized output and base images using the mask image
 - When finished with the loop, save the result
```

Input (transparent):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image with transparency
img = cv2.imread('black_circle_transp.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
height, width = img.shape[:2]
print(img.shape)

# extract the bgr channels and the alpha channel
bgr = img[:,:,0:3]
aa = img[:,:,3]
aa = cv2.merge([aa,aa,aa])

# create whatever color background you want, in this case white
background=np.full((500,500,3), (255,255,255), dtype=np.float64)

# create white image of the size you want
white=np.full((500,500,3), (255,255,255), dtype=np.float64)

# create black image of the size you want
black=np.zeros((500,500,3), dtype=np.float64)

# initialize output
result = background.copy()

# define top left corner x,y locations for circle offsets
xy_offsets = [(100,100), (150,150), (200,200)]

# insert bgr and alpha into white and black images respectively of desired output size and composite
for offset in xy_offsets:
    xoff = offset[0]
    yoff = offset[1]
    base = white.copy()
    base[yoff:height+yoff, xoff:width+xoff] = bgr
    mask = black.copy()
    mask[yoff:height+yoff, xoff:width+xoff] = aa
    result = (result * (255-mask) + base * mask)/255
    result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('black_circle_composite.png', result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.imshow("aa", aa)
cv2.imshow("bgr", bgr)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: how would you address those hairlines where the circles overlap? https://imgur.com/MRC9Ain

Comment: What hairlines? Are you looking at the anti-aliasing around the black. Is that from the input or from the process of creating the alpha channel?  I created my alpha channel. It was not from the OP. I just put an inverted copy of the input into the alpha channel of the image to start. So it is likely and artifact from the input anti-aliased circle on white background. To mitigate it, one could blur a little to smooth it and possible half threshold (only in the black area). Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @fmw42 Your result is what I want, that's perfect. 
However, the result in my machine is just the last circle in the loop, please check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3BKQ.png
- update 100,100 to the last pos `xy_offsets = [(200,200), (150,150), (100,100)]` and only the circle at that position shown - any idea of the difference on result?
- `alpha = 225`
- I added aa and bgr at the bottom of the image above, they look good

Comment: the edge pixels (value) were created by mixing black (foreground) and white (background) with some alpha. to recover the true foreground color, given a somehow recovered alpha, rearrange `value = fg*alpha + bg*(1-alpha)` => `value = alpha*(fg-bg) + bg` => `fg = (value - bg) / alpha + bg`, and that should give true black for all those edge pixels (instead of grayish to white), and let the alpha channel handle the fading. I won't post that as an answer because it'd be incomplete and nobody seems to notice this or care, so far.

Comment: `@Tuan Tran` There was a typo in the code that I posted. I have edited it. So copy it again and try it now. It works for me.

Comment: @fmw42 it works perfectly for my image now. Thank you :)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't have a basis of alpha, fg, bg - have to work on it so I will be able to debug myself